# value validation if already exist in the database

Tags: php, sql

I am new to php i have made a form where i have two fields  Code and Name  and i need to validate the value of name that it is already in the database but when i am  inserting the value in uppercase its not validating the value of name in both uppercase & lowercase vice versa here is my code

```
if(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country "
              ."WHERE $_POST['name']='$name' and $_POST['code']='$code'" )))
{
    echo "Sorry! Your details are already in our database";
} else {
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Certainly it won't make a case insensitive comparision. Different cases are different, not equal.

Comment: You should switch away from phps old `mysql` extension. It is depreciated due to major security issues. Use the newer `mysqli` extension or `PDO` for prepared statements.

Comment: @arkascha not true depending on the collation of the field in the database. What is the collation if the field in the database?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: [I see syntax error there...](http://codepad.org/dyPwbG0J). If you want to use in-string variables wrap `{}` around it - [example](http://codepad.org/qCbgWZbP). And I am pretty sure you are not sure what you are doing. Maybe start from some tutorial first, instead asking about syntax etc. at SO

Comment: Clear example where is error: http://codepad.org/FwVT0Gsf - it's php basic so i encourage you to start from some tutorial first. You also need to learn how to read php errors while debugging

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski - The main issue appears to be an invalid SQL statement...well, either that, or `$_POST['name']` is the worst column name ever.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski You are right. It was my mistake of being rude. I am really sorry! The OP has syntax error in his code itself.

Comment: @PraveenKumar it's ok, no hard feelings :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your columns are incorrect in your SQL statement (for one). Also, as other people have noted, please use the mysqli_* or PDO families of SQL statements.

```
<?php

$count = 0;
$name = strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : ""));
$code = strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['code']) ? $_POST['code'] : ""));

$query = "SELECT name FROM country WHERE LOWER(name)='".$name."' AND LOWER(code)='".$code."'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result != null)
{
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
}

if($count <= 0)
{
    echo "Sorry! Your details are already in our database";
} 
else
{
    // ...
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

1) Never use $_POST directly because your code is unsafe.
You need to filter this data. Here are some filter functions in PHP http://php.net/manual/fr/function.filter-var.php.

```
$username = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$code = filter_var($_POST['code'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Only then you can consider querying the database with these values.

2) If available to you I recommand you to use PDO http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer to the question? This should go into a comment...

Comment: Is it helping him to copy paste unsafe and crappy code ?

Comment: Certainly not, but... isn't that another issue? This still is no answer.